# Django logged_out.html page problem that redirect administration pages

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
```

This page is created successfully and working nice:

And Problem with these pages: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/` This page redirect me Django Administration Pages that message to login again but I don't want this.

I have placed my HTML file in

```
..templates/registration/logged_out.html
```

And checked spelling error multiple time to see why not working.

**My urls files:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('catalog.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and my **logged_out.html** is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
  <p>Logged out!</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Click here to login again.</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Can any tell me what's wrong with it? How to fix this?

Comment: take a look at LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL in your settings, here is the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined [`LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url) in your settings, then [`LogoutView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView) will redirect to it.

Check to see if you have defined `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` in your settings, and remove it if you have.

Comment: I added this:     STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'LogoutView'

Comment: but it show this message:  NoReverseMatch at /accounts/logout/

Reverse for 'LogoutView' not found. 'LogoutView' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. If you set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'LogoutView'`, then the `LogoutView` will try to reverse that URL and redirect to it. I asked you to *remove it* from settings, or you can set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None`.

Comment: I set : LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None and it redirect administration pages

Comment: It not redirects me to my own page

Comment: Where is the logout link that you are clicking. Check its URL and make sure it is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/` and not the Django admin's logout link. If you copy and paste `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/` into your browser bar, then I don't think you'll be redirected if you have `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None`.

Comment: Setting:LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/ this is the url and it redirect me to adminstraion logout page

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions then. Hope you figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time and care, i am gonna watch tutorial for this